# joining two table with different conditions of different column

Tags: sql-server

### tbl_User

```
ID  mobileno        dateofregistration       registrationstate 
44  1674174925  2011-04-18 10:17:30.670         0
45  1677864168  2011-03-31 10:20:22.450         1
46  1677864161  2011-04-18 20:47:35.293         0
47  1674174925  2011-03-29 09:28:55.200         1
48  1674174967  2011-03-29 09:28:55.100         1
```

### Tbl_cdr

```
slno   ano            startTime
0   1677864161  2011-03-29 14:37:35.000
0   1677864161  2011-03-29 15:36:47.000
0   1677864165  2011-03-31 15:07:00.000
0   1677864166  2011-03-31 15:04:13.000
0   1677864167  2011-03-29 14:36:17.000
0   1677864167  2011-03-31 15:04:46.000
0   1677864168  2011-03-31 15:00:07.000
0   1677864168  2011-03-31 15:01:39.000
0   1677864168  2011-03-31 15:07:44.000
0   1677864168  2011-03-31 15:08:14.000
```

### Output

```
   Date    ActFail  NewAct     RenFail  SuccessRen
29/03/2011   1        2           0         0
31/03/2011   3        1           0         0
1.Date  : group by startTime ;
2. ActFail : Count(*) From Tbl_cdr with condition ano!=mobileno.`
3.NewAct : `count (*) from Tbl_user with condition registrationstate=1`
4.RenFail : `count * from Tbl_cdr with condition (ano=mobileno and registrationstate=0)`
5.SuccessRate : Count(*) from tbl_user when only registratonstate changed from 0 to 1

     All query will be groupby Tbl_cdr.startTime and between user given timelimit.
```

i,hv tried with this,but in vain

```
select
  Convert(varchar(10), startTime,103) as Date,
  count(*) As ActivationFail,
  (Select COUNT(*) from tbl_User where registrationstate='1') as NewActivation
from Tbl_cdr c
  left join Tbl_User u  on c.ano = u.mobileno
where u.id is null and startTime between @date1 and @date2
group by Convert(varchar(10),startTime,103)
```

any help,Plz.. is it possible to show all the 5 column in a single table with the above conditions???

Comment: Also FYI these are not `JOIN`s.  All your conditions are either inequalities or just `WHERE` clause filters.

Comment: Is there any link between two tables.

Comment: What you want is very 'unclear' and confusing. Please explain what you have, and what you want...

Comment: @JNK: Possibly the join is the intended operation, and its difficulty for the OP the reason behind asking this question.

Comment: @Anik, please describe in your question what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to change your database scheme. Let you think about denormalizing.